# Using non-zero values from columns in function - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

I am having the below dataframe and would like to calculate the difference between columns 'animal1' and 'animal2' over their sum within a function while only taking into consideration the values that are bigger than 0 in each of the columns 'animal1' and 'animal2.
How could I do this?

import pandas as pd

```
animal1 = pd.Series({'Cat': 4, 'Dog': 0,'Mouse': 2, 'Cow': 0,'Chicken': 3})
animal2 = pd.Series({'Cat': 2, 'Dog': 3,'Mouse': 0, 'Cow': 1,'Chicken': 2})
data = pd.DataFrame({'animal1':animal1, 'animal2':animal2})

def animals():
    data['anim_diff']=(data['animal1']-data['animal2'])/(data['animal1']+ ['animal2'])
return data['anim_diff'].abs().idxmax()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need check all rows are greater by `0` with [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with test [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
def animals(data):
    data['anim_diff']=(data['animal1']-data['animal2'])/(data['animal1']+ data['animal2'])
    return data['anim_diff'].abs().idxmax()

df = data[data.gt(0).all(axis=1)].copy()
#alternative for not equal 0
#df = data[data.ne(0).all(axis=1)].copy()
print (df)
         animal1  animal2
Cat            4        2
Chicken        3        2

print(animals(df))
Cat
```